# PHAssetCreationRequest not working

Tags: swift, video, ios9

I'm trying to use a PHAssetCreationRequest to move a video file from my documents folder to the camera roll. I can't find a good example on how to do this from the Apple documentation or anywhere on the web. The code below fails, but I'm not sure why. Do I need to somehow trigger the request in the completion block?

I've verified that the movie files exist in my documents directory (I downloaded the app assets onto my Mac and the videos work fine).

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in
    let request = PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(movieUrl!)
            }, completionHandler: { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                print(success)
                print(error)
})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My example is working for me

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in
            PHAssetCreationRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(outputFileURL)
            }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
                if success {
                    print("it works!!!")
                    self.removeVideo()
                }
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
```